# Find out who deleted certain data

Tags: windows-7, logging

Someone deleted data from my windows 7 system. I want to find out who.

The data is shared.

Are there any logs that could help me?

Comment: In what way is it "shared"? Also, if it was "very important data" as was mentioned in the original question, you should have had a backup. Might not feel helpful to hear now, but learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **NO**. There is no logs for file access available by default in Windows 7.

Long answer:

If the users accessing the files are not members of Administrators group, you can set up [file access auditing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399) in order to create logs of who accessed a specific file or directory. You'll see all relevant file access logs in the Event Manager. Of course, you cannot do this retroactively, you need to set up this logging in advance.

Users must not have Administrator rights. If the user has Administrator permissions, he can trivially bypass this logging, or alter the logs to cover his tracks.